# The "Weeping Angels" (statues) from Doctor Who

Tags: copyright

I haven't been able to find any clearance on this. There are these "monsters" in Doctor Who called the Weeping Angels. I love the concept and would want to use it in a VR game.

But are these copyrighted, is the actually statue itself or even the concept of having them move only when you see them claimed? I understand things like the daleks or his robot little dog can be copyrighted but an angel statue?

For reference here is one of them:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So Angel Statues are not copyrighted in and of themselves.   Specific examples might be claimed by an artist, but not a general Angel concept.  Similarly Statues that Move when you are not looking are not copyrighted.  In fact, the internet web series SCP had a fast moving statue that only moved when it wasn't being watched before the first appearance of the Weeping Angels.  The series "Gargoyles" feature creatures that turned to stone during the day... they would often freeze in different poses that, if someone unaware of this fact saw them, would make them moving statues.

It all depends on how close to the Weeping Angels your own intepretation is.  The specific Weeping Angels from Doctor Who are copyrighted and they will sue if you do a complete copy.  But moving statues are not new at all.